# How can I populate a select list of Iana timezones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, timezone

Is there a simple way to populate a list of Iana timezones in html? I cannot find any widget which can generate these lists for me?

I have checked with momentJS and with JQuery to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

It seems something like this will do : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Timezone-Picker-with-jQuery-Moment-js-Timezones/